# Mathematica 7 showing answer step by step

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-7

I would like to know the steps Mathematica applies to obtain a result.
I have

```
Limit[n^Log[2, n]/1.001^n, n -> \[Infinity]]
```

and Mathematica shows 0 but I want to know how it got that result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematica can't do that, it uses algorithms which are very different from what you want to see.

There is [a set of functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/TuningAndDebugging.html) which will return some information about calculation process for some specific entry, but their outputs are total mess - those are meant as development diagnostic, not as help with homework or preparation for exam.

For some types of problems such as limits, integrals, derivatives etc. you can use [Math Assistant on Web](http://wood.mendelu.cz/math/maw-html/?), which will describe whole solution process in detail.